# Getting AMAZON.NUMBER type slot in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Currently attempting to write my first Alexa skill, a simple calculator. I am trying to get it started just by working on an addition intent. I have been getting a litany of errors and haven't found anything well documented on this issue.

Here is the relevant node.js code:

```
var https = require('https');
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

try {

if (event.session.new) {
  // New Session
  console.log("NEW SESSION");
}

switch (event.request.type) {

  case "LaunchRequest":
    // Launch Request
    console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`);
    context.succeed(
      generateResponse(
        buildSpeechletResponse("Launch Request", "Welcome to Pro Calculator", "", true),
        {}
      )
    );
    break;

  case "IntentRequest":
    // Intent Request
    console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`);
            onIntent(event.request,
                event.session,
              function callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse){
                    context.succeed(generateResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
    break;

  case "SessionEndedRequest":
    // Session Ended Request
    console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`);
    break;

  default:
    context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);

}

  } catch(error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }

};

// Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
console.log("onIntent requestId=" + intentRequest.requestId
    + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var cardTitle = "Addition";

var intent = intentRequest.intent,
    intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

// dispatch custom intents to handlers here
    switch(intentName){

        //addition
        case "addIntent":
            var valA = this.event.request.intent.slots.valA;
            var valB = this.event.request.intent.slots.valB;
            var ans = valA + valB;
            callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, `The answer is ${ans}`, "", "true"));
            break;

        default:
            throw "Invalid intent";
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant json code:

```
{
    "intent": "addIntent"
},
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "valA",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "name": "valB",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
    }
  ],
}
```

And finally, the error being generated:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please share you handler function

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan updated to include more json code

Comment: You intent schema doesn't look correct. I have updated it in the answer. Please try with that

Answer (score 0):

your intent schema in the interaction model doesn't look correct. Please try with below intent schema,

```js
{
    "intents": [
      {
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "valA",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
          },
          {
            "name": "valB",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
          }
        ],
        "intent": "addIntent"
      }
      
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your intent schema is not proper as told by @Vijayanath Viswanathan, change your intent schema by below schema:

```
{
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "addIntent",
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "valA",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
          },
          {
            "name": "valB",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
}
```

Then you have to change your code to get slots value.

Change to this,

> var valA = this.event.request.intent.slots.valA.value;
>
> var valB = this.event.request.intent.slots.valB.value;

instead of this,

> var valA = this.event.request.intent.slots.valA;
>
> var valB = this.event.request.intent.slots.valB;

By this changes, you will get values of slots.